# Running a program in succession on the same port

Tags: java, linux, sockets, centos, thrift

I am running some java code on CentOS 5

```
java Something.java &
```

that creates a socket on a certain port....say `9090`..however, the code doesn't run completely and so I `Ctrl-C` out of it.

When I try running the program again it errors out saying it cannot connect to the port `9090`.

When I change the port number to some arbitrary thing like `9010`...everything works again (except for the fact that `Something.java` gets stuck)....churn and repeat

What's going on? I'd like to be able to use one consistent port for this stuff...is there some background process I am not getting rid of everytime?

Thanks!

Comment: what does your `ps aux` show -- are you sure you're not leaving "something" running which keeps that port open? Also try `lsof` which shows what application is using each port opened.

Comment: lsof -i :port gives me a command not found error...how do I get lsof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might happen because the OS has some quarantine delay until another process can reuse the address.

The C library provides the socket option `SO_REUSEADDR` which can be set to avoid this. A quick web search indicates that `setReuseAddress(boolean)` in `java.net.ServerSocket` can be used to set this option.

Answer (score 0):

It may take some time for the JVM to actually finish the program and release the socket.

You can manually close the socket when the software is terminated by ctrl-c with `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...)`, which I greatly recommend for all the software that is running in the background and uses sockets. Should help.

Comment: do I just paste this as is in the main method?

Comment: I put that in my `main`, but before I start the thread that handles the socket. As for what the `addShutdownHook` does and how to deal with it, check e.g. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html